# web source directory shows when request is https instead of http

Tags: http, laravel-4, https, xampp, localhost

Good Day,

How can I prevent showing the directory of my source code when request is `https`? I am currently running my files in a local network and I found out the if I access the address using `https:\\site.ur;` I then get a warning on chrome (if I proceed Ill be redirected to its source directory) If I used `http:\\site.url` its running I am running on apache and windows 7 server.. thanks for the help

Comment: You seem to have a server running on port 443. You'll have to find out which one it is and turn it off

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir @Pekka웃 but I cant quite understand what do you mean by it.. should I turn off the port or you mean something else.. sorry ..

Comment: You have a server program running that listens to the port. Do you have a server admin? They should know what is going on

Comment: ohh okay.. in my case its the xampp or apache right? unfortunately I am the server admin and im quite a beginner on this.. I just found out this thing is happening :)